# (Android) Show progress dialog not use AsyncTask

Tags: android

When user click refresh button, start http connection.

The connection may be long, so I want show progress dialog.(not progress bar)

But It shows after search.

Here my code in MainActivity.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.tool_btnRefresh:

            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Now searching...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Horizontal);
            progressDialog.show(); // not showing here.
            Search(0);
            // show here.
     }
}
```

And Search function.

```
public void Search(int idx)
{
    NetCheck nc = new NetCheck(this, false);

    if (!nc.checkNetwork()) // check the network connection
    {
        return;
    }

    final NetTask nt = new NetTask(); 
    // NetTask is class, that extends Callable.
    // connect http server in call() and get return value.

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
            Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
    );

    Future<Map<String, Object>> future = executorService.submit(nt);
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    try
    {
        Map<String, Object> result = future.get(); // get return value.
        list.add(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

What's the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the progress dialog is showing in UI thread.

Then the problem will be in `search()` call.

There must be something in there competing on resource in UI thread.

I recommend you to try to put the `NetCheck` usage inside the Executors.

e.g.

```
public void Search(int idx) {   
   ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
      Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
   );

   Future<Map<String, Object>> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
      // Do everything inside here. If exception or error met, return null
   });
```